# Calculations with 3 differents list

Tags: python, list, coordinates, calculation

I am with a problem with calculations with 3 differents list.

I have this lists:

```
center_x= [1.340, 8.54065065, 3.718, 5.83]
center_y= [1.672, 1.67, 7.47, 4.71]
center_z= [-0.451, -1.389, 7.523, 8.15]
```

Each list has a spatial coordinate, that is, center_x[1], center_y[1], center_z[1], form a coordinate of type (x,y,z).

I need to calculate the distances between these coordinates, like this pairs 1-2, 2-3, 3-4 . I tried like this:

```
for i in range(len(centro_x)):
    print( 'Dists :',(( ((center_x[i+1]-center_x[i]**2)+ center_y[i+1]-center_y[i]**2)+ (center_z[i+1]-center_z[i]**2)) **(1/2)) )
```

But only be able to calculate for the first pair, 1-2.

And than obtain this error:

```
dist 3.0513998021801334
dist (6.261343210163308e-16+10.225549463768164j)
dist (6.351600500021062e-16+10.372950804171936j)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/josepinto/Desktop/quadrangular/auxiliar.py", line 81, in <module>
print(  'dist',(( ((centro_x[i+1]-centro_x[i]**2)+ centro_y[i+1]-centro_y[i]**2)+ 
(centro_z[i+1]-centro_z[i]**2)) **(1/2)) )
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Someone can help me?
Thanks

Comment: You probably need to change `range(len(centro_x))` to `range(len(centro_x) - 1)`

Comment: `(center_x[i+1]-center_x[i]**2)` seems to be a typo. You probably intend `(center_x[i+1]-center_x[i])**2`

Answer (score 2):

The parenthesis are placed wrong and the range of your for loop is slightly mistaken to compute the distances between coordinates:

```
centro_x= [1.340, 8.54065065, 3.718, 5.83]
centro_y= [1.672, 1.67, 7.47, 4.71]
centro_z= [-0.451, -1.389, 7.523, 8.15]

for i in range(len(centro_x)-1):
    print( 'Dists :',((centro_x[i+1]-centro_x[i])**2 + (centro_y[i+1]-centro_y[i])**2+ (centro_z[i+1]-centro_z[i])**2) ** (1/2)  )
```

Since you are using i+1 in your print statement the error is thrown when it gets to the last element in centro_x, as i+1 from there does not refer to a valid position in the array; hence the error

Eventually, you could use the `numpy.linalg.norm` to compute the distance without a for loop

```
centro_x= [1.340, 8.54065065, 3.718, 5.83]
centro_y= [1.672, 1.67, 7.47, 4.71]
centro_z= [-0.451, -1.389, 7.523, 8.15]
import numpy as np
centro= np.array([[1.340, 8.54065065, 3.718, 5.83],[1.672, 1.67, 7.47, 4.71],[-0.451, -1.389, 7.523, 8.15]])
dist = np.linalg.norm(np.diff(centro),axis=0)
print(dist)
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because of the +1 in the index
try:

```
for i in range(1,len(center_x)):
    print( 'Dists :',(( ((center_x[i-1]-center_x[i]**2)+ center_y[i-1]-center_y[i]**2)+ (center_z[i-1]-center_z[i]**2)) **(1/2)) )
```

my code:

```
center_x= [1.340, 8.54065065, 3.718, 5.83]
center_y= [1.672, 1.67, 7.47, 4.71]
center_z= [-0.451, -1.389, 7.523, 8.15]
for i in range(1,len(center_x)):
    print( 'Dists :',(( ((center_x[i-1]-center_x[i]**2)+ center_y[i-1]-center_y[i]**2)+ (center_z[i-1]-center_z[i]**2)) **(1/2)) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You're out of range `IndexError: list index out of range` since you start with first index [0] and reach the 5th index [4] which is not in the list. So you have to change this line

```
for i in range(len(center_x)):
```

to

```
for i in range(len(center_x) - 1):
```

**another hint:** there's a parenthesis problem placed here in the formula you wrote, which need to be written correctly to avoid miscalculations.